# postgresql -- create a materialized view by inserting data from multiple tables

Tags: postgresql

I have multiple tables containing the same columns. i want to build an aggregated table containing the data from all these tables. I'm wondering if materialized view can do this. If so, what's the query like? I have no problem getting and filtering data from one table, but I have no idea if it's possible to do it with multiple tables

the structure of my db currently looks like this

```
db
|
| - table1 
| - table2
| - table3
```

and I'm trying to get data from all of them and put into a view (and update when content in table# changes)

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what the [UNION](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-union.html) operator is for. You should be able to do something like this:

```
SELECT col1, col2 FROM table1 UNION SELECT col1, col2 FROM table2;
```

There's a tutorial for UNION [here](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-union/).

Comment: Thank you. Exactly what I'm looking for.